# Facing issue while creating a task using asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I am trying to build a python script which does some work(main()) when an update is received from the database (func2()). I am using a while loop to check for update every 20 seconds. Also, to make sure that in case when my script restarts, all the previous instances of main() function start running again (func2 is doing that). Below is the code template which I am currently using :

```
async def func1():
    # fetches data from database and starts the func2 and runs main function 
    # using it.
    group = await asyncio.gather(func2(),*[main(i) for_some_i_from_database])
    asyncio.create_task(group)

async def func2():
    # constantly checks for an new update in the database 
    # under a loop and executes another function 
    # using that information
    returns asyncio.create_task(main(x))

async def main(x):
    client = TelegramClient(x,api_id,api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    @client.on(events.NewMessage())
    async def handler():
        print(event.message.text)
    await client.run_untill_disconnected()
    

asyncio.run(func1())
```

The script on restarting, fetches updates from database and restarts previous instances of main() function successfully. Also, it is successfully fetching new updates to database concurrently.
But there is a problem with running new instances of main() function. When I try to run the new instance of main function (while old instances are running)using func2(), the new instance doesn't work (while the old ones are still working). I am not so comfortable with asyncio. But, I need to use it to make my script work faster. What am I doing wrong here...? Also, is there a better way to do it..?

UPDATE : I forgot to mention that when database updates, the new instance of main() function starts but the loop doesn't work. I mean the new instance of main() starts for once and stops. Where am I wrong...?

Comment: Does your main() function contain "await" statements?  If not, it will not release control of the event loop once it gets control.  Any new tasks that you create will not get control until the currently running task performs an "await."  Perhaps if you provided some more code in func2() and main() it would help to clarify the situation.

Comment: @Paul Cornelius I have updated the needful and I hope it will be sufficient information to get a clarity of situation.

Comment: First you told us that a new instance of main doesn't work while the old ones are still working.  Now you say that it starts but the loop doesn't work.  The code you present contains no loop.  Your code, as it stands, can't be run by anyone else.  Please understand that you are talking to a community of people who don't know what you're trying to do, and the only thing they know about your problem is what you tell them.  Can you provide more specifics of what is happening, what you see, and what you expect to see, etc.?

Comment: The code in `func1` can't possibly work as written. `group` gets assigned the return value of `gather`, which is a tuple. Then you pass that tuple to `asyncio.create_task()`, which expects a coroutine object. The queestion is not answerable as written.